# How to solve waiting for RPC response in GWT?

Tags: gwt, rpc

I know that the RPC is asynchronous but how Can in other way (other than waiting for response) to solve this problem:

```
public static String htsl(String sentence)
{
    final DataBaseAsync db = GWT.create(DataBase.class);
    String cookie = staticContent.getCookie("ll");
    String shortcut = cookie.split("/")[1];
    final String[] lala = new String[1];
    database.getTranslated(sentence, shortcut, new AsyncCallback<String>() {



        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            lala[0]=result;

            //this result I want to return in static function htsl... ?

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
    //here I have blank result, because RPC is slower than te return.. 
    And i have always blank result
    return lala[0];

}
```

I know that is not good, but.. If it is no working solution for this, how to wait for response?

Answer (score 1):

Make `htsl` asynchronous (non-blocking, i.e. with a callack for the response rather than a return value)

Comment: See Jeroen's answer, which is the same as mine but with sample code. You could also use a [`Callback`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Callback.html) or a custom interface as argument though, and call it back from the RPC's `AsyncCallback`. The custom interface could have only an `onSuccess` (which I'd rather call `onTranslated` then) if you don't want to expose error handling to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like so:

```
public static String htsl(String sentence, AsyncCallback<String> myCallback) {
    final DataBaseAsync db = GWT.create(DataBase.class);
    String cookie = staticContent.getCookie("ll");
    String shortcut = cookie.split("/")[1];
    final String[] lala = new String[1];

    database.getTranslated(sentence, shortcut, myCallback);
}
```

Then you let some other class implement AsyncCallback, pass it as the `myCallback` argument to the `htsl` method and Bob's your uncle.